# Adding dot between two characters in java string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string:

```
String x = "10";
```

Now I want to add `.` between the numbers and print it like this

```
1.0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you want the result to be with an input of "5"? What about "123"?

Comment: You need to be a little more clear, you only want the solution for this particular case or a more general solution?

Comment: What is the rule for inserting the `.`? At the second position? Before the last position?

Comment: i have a string whose value is 10
i want to make a new string which just put "." between 2 numbers

Comment: If you only need to do this once, why not just change x to 1.0  ... I feel like im missing something. Adding a char to a string is a very very easy problem

Comment: i need to do it in a loop of variables

Comment: Okay, see that is what we're looking for... what is the rule for adding the period?

Comment: like "10,20,30,40"  ...
i want to manipulate a string so that it add "." between 2 numbers ?

Comment: yes..  how to put period between 2  numbers

Comment: You should read up on some java tutorials, this is a very very basic function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can split the string into the first character and the rest of the string, and then insert a dot `'.'` in between, like this:

```
String res = x.substring(0,1)+"."+x.substring(1);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            the first digit     the rest of the string
```

You can also use `replaceAll` to do it on longer strings, like this:

```
String orig = "19,28,37,46";
System.out.println(orig.replaceAll("(\\d)(\\d)", "$1.$2"));
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/vWBqe)

```
1.9,2.8,3.7,4.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to better decouple the value and its representation.

Answer (score 1):

If the String is always a 2-digit number :

```
String result = x.charAt(0) + "." + x.charAt(1);
```

Comment: That will actually just add the character values, which won't give the answer you want.

Comment: Changing the `'.'` to `"."` will force the `+` to be used for string concatenation.

Comment: @GregHewgill Woops I did not thing about that and thought being clever using chars instead of Strings. I fixed it.

Comment: Downvoters are probably not here anymore. Since you had same idea like mine but was faster +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

this function can accepts all number and returns a dotted string, with small touches it can accepts many in other types of data an return data with options

```
    fun getStringWithDot(nums: Int): String {
var str = ""
val istr = nums.toString()
for (ch in istr.indices){
    if (ch == istr.length-1){
        str += istr.substring(0,1)
    }else{
        str += istr.substring(ch,ch+1) + "."
    }

}
return str
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[])

{
Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);

int arr[];

int number;

number=S.nextInt();

int length=Integer.toString(number).length();

arr=new int[length];

char arr2[];

arr2=new char[length];

int count=0;

char arr3[];

arr3=new char[length];

String Q=Integer.toString(number);

for(int i=0;i<arr3.length;i++)

{

    System.out.print(Q.charAt(i)+".");

}

}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated compared to the accepted anwser.